# Exe in Windows is crashing while appending wstring when calling GetWindowsDirectory

Tags: c++, windows, crash, append, wstring

I am appending wstring. I have "C:\Windows" in wstring. And I am appending "\system32\config\" to it . by following code.

```
#define MAX_PATH 260
 wstring wstrWindowsDirectory;
    if(0 != GetWindowsDirectory((LPWSTR)wstrWindowsDirectory.c_str(),MAX_PATH)) 
    {
        if(!wstrWindowsDirectory.empty()) {
            wstrWindowsDirectory += L"\System32\\config\\";
        }
}

But its crashing..
please help me.. 
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: A `wstring` is a `const char*` array, so you should manually allocate enough length.

Answer (score 3):

When you write stuff into a string via `c_str()`, it doesn't grow automatically.

Therefore, there's no guarantee that `wstrWindowsDirectory` is big enough to contain the path you're trying to write into it.

You need to use `wstring::reserve()` before calling `GetWindowsDirectory()`.